# Insert character at end of string in R, except for the last element

Tags: r

I looked but failed to find an answer to how to add a character to the end of each and every element in a string vector in R, **except the last one**...

Consider the following:

```
data <- c("cat", "dog", "mouse", "lion")
```

I'd like to apply a function that pastes a "," at the end of each element such that the result is:

```
[1] "cat,", "dog,", "mouse,", "lion"
```

apply functions? for loop? any help is appreciated...

Comment: `paste0(data, ",")`. You didn't add `,` after `lion` intentionally or not?

Comment: I think you need `data[-length(data)] <- paste0(data[-length(data)], ',')` or ` `strsplit(paste(data, collapse=', '), ' ')[[1]]`

Comment: intentionally, what I'm doing is hacking a negative select statement in sql, so last item would not have a comma @DavidArenburg

Comment: So you should go with akruns answer then. He probably should post it.

Comment: I definitely say post it : )

Comment: your title is horribly misleading here.

Comment: absolutely right @SerbanTanasa - has been edited...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this in a couple of ways:

1. Subset the 'data' without the last element,  paste `,`, and assign that to the original data (without last element)

   ```
   data[-length(data)] <- paste0(data[-length(data)], ',')
   ```
2. Use `strsplit` after collapsing it as a string

   ```
   strsplit(paste(data, collapse=', '), ' ')[[1]]
   ```

Comment: Can you explain what this `[[1]]` means and how it is able to leave the last element without collapsing.

Comment: @ambrish `strsplit` returns a list of results, so the `[[1]]` is extracting the first item in the list (in this case the only item).
See the output of `strsplit(c("abc 123", "bcd 456"), " ")` for example.

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old question, but since I suppose people (like me) still end here, they may want to consider easy solutions offered by more recent but fairly common packages. They offer slightly different options.

**Option 1: Knitr**

```
data <- c("cat", "dog", "mouse", "lion")
knitr::combine_words(data, before = '`')

# `cat`, `dog`, `mouse`, and `lion`
```

**Option 2: Glue**

```
data <- c("cat", "dog", "mouse", "lion")
glue::glue_collapse(x = data, ", ", last = " and ")

# cat, dog, mouse and lion
```

Comment: I actually cam here looking for your second option so many thanks for that :)

I don't think your suggestions answer the question though.

Comment: @Moohan oh, you're right! Probably posted it under the wrong question after some time looking for solutions...